# Java - Insert an object into a queue but got the exception in java even the node have been initialised

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, queue

I am a beginner of programming. I have been searching for solving the null pointer exception. The null pointer exception happens because the object has not been initialised. However it happens when I implement a code for enqueuing the data of an object into a queue although I have initialised the object.

The below is the code for the enqueue

```
    public void addToList(Human human){
    //When the list is empty, insert the human data
    if(isEmpty()){
        Node temp = new Node(human);
        temp.setNext(this.head);
        this.head = temp;
        numNodes++;
    }
    else{
        Node current = this.head;
        //If the list is not empty, the new human data will be enqueued based on the priority
        //If the current data has a lower priority, temp data (new human) will be inserted into the queue first
        if(current.getHuman().getPriority() < temp.getHuman().getPriority()){

            temp.setNext(this.head);
            this.head = temp;
            numNodes++;
        }
        else{
            //If the current data has a higher priority , it will traverse the queue until there is space(current.next = null) for temp data to insert
            while (current.getNext() != null){
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            current.setNext(temp);
            temp = this.head;
            //temp.setNext(this.head);
            numNodes++;
        }
    }
}
```

Regardless of the priority, even if I delete the code for priority, I cannot run the enqueue method after the file is compiled.

It shows me the below null pointer exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Node.setNext(Node)" because "<local2>" is null
```

The Node class is as below:

```
public class Node{
protected Node next;
protected Human human;

public Node(Human new_human){
    this.human= new_human;
    this.next = null;
}

public Node getNext(){
    return next;
}

public void setNext(Node new_next){
    this.next = new_next;
}

public Patient getHuman(){
    return human;
}

public void setHuman(Human hu){
    this.human= hu;
}
```

}

Did I do something wrong ? I have searched for solutions but still have not fixed. The potential problem should be the "temp.setNext(this.head)", but if I have already made "Node temp = new Node(human)", there should not be null. I wonder if my initialisation is incorrect. I have tried "this.head = new Node(human)" but still did not work.

Hope anyone can give me some advice to fix this problem.
Thank you very much.

Comment: `temp.getHuman().getPriority()` - where is `temp` defined?

Comment: @Scary Wombat Thank you for reminding, I forgot that the scope of temp only cover code inside the "if". But, even I added back the "Node temp = new Node(human)" inside the "else", the same null pointer exception statement still happened.